# What is the meaning of a non-abstract, non-virtual, body-less method in an abstract class?

Tags: c#

Starting out in C# through ASP .NET Core, I keep seeing abstract classes which have a bunch of method declarations that are neither abstract nor virtual, meaning I don't have to implement them, but I also must not implement them. Then also, they have no implementation by themself.

An example of this is the method `WriteAsync` from `Stream.cs` in `System.IO`:

```cs
public abstract class Stream : MarshalByRefObject, IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable {
    // ...
    public Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
    // ...
}
```

What does this construct mean? Why is this code legal?

I am asking because I am trying to implement `System.IO.Stream`.

Comment: Are you sure you're *actually* looking at source code rather than the generated view based just on the metadata?

Comment: See one implementation [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Stream.cs,731).

Comment: That one is not body-less, it's an expression method.

Comment: That code *isn't* legal, it's just a way for the decompiler to present the `WriteAsync` method without its implementation. Note that a need to implement `Stream` yourself is quite rare -- you can almost always get by with either using a higher class like `StreamReader`, or wrapping an existing `Stream` instance and forwarding almost all methods.

Comment: These comments explain a lot. Thanks. I am still not sure how I can now best decide which of the methods marked `virtual`, but not `abstract`, I then need to override. In my concrete case, in my implementation of `Write`, I called `Write` on a `Stream` object I wrapped, but that object, unbeknownst to me and my implementation, does not support asynchronous writes. I also see explicit checks for implementation, e.g. line 766 in the sources linked by Sweeper, which is another construct I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Unfortunately `async` support was necessarily hacked onto streams later and implementations couldn't be required to support it retroactively, which is why the `WriteAsync` overloads that are `virtual` couldn't be made `abstract`. The default implementations wrap the `Begin...`/`End...` implementations of old-style async I/O. Simply forwarding should still work, if your intent isn't to add support for asynchronous operations to a stream that doesn't support them. If that *is* your intent, you should definitely reconsider, as async-over-sync wrappers are nasty, especially at this level.